# How do i make it so that spaces generate so the outcome is different

Tags: java, for-loop, whitespace, println

I would like the output to have 9 spaces then a star, 8 spaces then two stars, 7 spaces and 3 stars and so on until 10 stars at the bottom.
How can I generate the spaces?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ThreeDotTwelvea
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final int max_rows = 1;
        for (int row = 10; row  >= max_rows; row--)
        {
            for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
                System.out.print ("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write the pattern you are trying to explain

Comment: * 
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********

Comment: it doesnt come out like i type it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public class ThreeDotTwelvea {

    final static int NO_OF_ROWS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = NO_OF_ROWS - i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Comment: what if i wanted the code to output 10 stars, space 9 stars, two space 8 stars, three spaces 7 stars and so on.